# Rails 4 ajax call not getting to the right controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails 4 project.
In the views/users/index.html.erb page I have an ajax call:

```
 $ ->
   sendMessage = () ->
     email = $('#contact-email').val()
     subject = $('#contact-subject').val()
     body = $('#contact-body').val()

     data =
       "email": email
       "subject": subject
       "body": body
       "authenticity_token": $('input[name=authenticity_token]').val()

     $('#ajax-contact-form').hide()
     $('.contact.success-message').html("Thank you, #{email}. We&apos;ll be in touch.")

     posting = $.ajax '/contacts',
       type: 'POST'
       data: JSON.stringify(data)
       dataType: 'json'
       contentType: 'application/json'

     posting.done (data) ->
       console.log "done"

  $('#ajax-contact-form').on 'submit', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    sendMessage()
```

When I click the button I can see the done on the console, and also the form passed correctly. But in the terminal, it seems it is going to users_controller#index function, and not contacts_controller#create.
Here are the routes:

```
 post 'contacts' => 'contacts#create', as: :contact, defaults: { format: :json }
```

It is not going inside this controller/function.

ROUTES:

```
contact POST     /contacts(.:format)   contacts#create {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: The requested url in the ajax call is: Request URL:http://localhost:3000/ so definitly missing something.

Comment: Can you show us the `rake routes` and more of the JS?

Comment: You need to remove '/contacts' and add it as url.  i.e url: '/contacts', type: 'POST' ......

Comment: It usually works like this, I mean in terms of syntax, I think it might be more a route problems (absolute or not), I was wondering if it was adding '/contacts' to the initial route '/users/index' ?

Comment: is it some login issue ? is the user logged in ?

Comment: I don't think it is linked to wether the user is logged or not, the email etc is written in the form.

Comment: I removed coffeescript and wrote it with javaScript and it is working... no idea why! Maybe it was the url: '/contacts' as suggested by @Addicted

Comment: @chelo - I would like you to up vote my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: '/contacts',
   type: 'POST',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json'
```

})